# Using NumberString, DigitCharacter, or a similar directive to find all string representations of integers in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a text file containing many, many lines of text like `test` in the following:

```
test = "word  123  456    7890.000      0.12000";
```

I would like to extract all of the "string representations of integers." However, I need to be clear about what I would like.  In `test` above, I would like the output to be:

```
{"123", "456"}
```

since I am only interested in *actual*, *isolated* (delimited by spaces) string representations of integers. Yes, `7890` is an integer, but in `test` above, it is not isolated, so I do not want my function to return it (since `7890.000` is a decimal).

In the case of `test`, I could use this:

```
StringCases[test, Repeated[DigitCharacter, 3]][[1 ;; 2]]
```

which returns

```
{"123", "456"}
```

However, this is not general, because my string may contain more than two string representations of integers.  So I would like my function to also take this input:

```
test = "word  123  456  123    7890.000      0.12000";
```

and return:

```
{"123", "456", "123"}
```

I have thought about using `StringSplit` followed by `ToExpression` and `IntegerQ`, but this seems like it would be very (unnecessarily?) complicated.  Perhaps Mathematica has something better built in that I can use?

Do you have any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I quite like Mathematica's `StringExpression`.  A bit longer than regular expressions but easier to read.

```
StringCases[test, " " ~~ d : DigitCharacter.. ~~ " " -> d]
```

> `{"123", "456", "123"}`

(Of course this does require two spaces between integers).

Comment: You don't actually need two spaces since you can set the option `Overlaps->True`.

Answer (score 7):

Regular Expressions are your friend:

```
StringTrim[StringCases["word  123  456  123    7890.000      0.12000", RegularExpression[" \\d+ "]]]
```

This returns

```
{"123", "456", "123"}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with `Select` and `StringCases` with `NumberString` as:

```
Select[StringCases[test, NumberString], IntegerQ@ToExpression@# &]
(* {"123", "456", "123"} *)
```

Add a `Rationalize` to the test if you also need integer numbers with the head `Real`.