# How to convert string to real numbers when there are many spaces in them?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, conversion

I have generated a string list

```
"      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000"
```

I want to convert them into real numbers however, when I write

```
ToExpression["      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000"]
```

I get 0., which is not so pleasing.

further when I enter

```
    ToExpression["      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000",InputForm,Hold]
```

I get

```
Hold[3212 8. 75 61 74 3 58 0.]
```

Where the two 1 has been lost.

Therefore I am here asking for help.

Comment: closely related: [8938](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8938/5478)

Comment: A space between the numbers is implicit multiplication. Furthermore, at (I believe) parsing time (if you input `Hold[1 2]` directly, the `1` is retained) the `1`s in the multiplication expression are considered redundant and dropped from the result. If you look closely, actually *three* ones have been lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = "      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000";
ImportString[s, "Table"]
```

Or using `ReadList`:

```
str = StringToStream[s];
list = ReadList[str, Number(*, RecordLists -> True*)];
Close[str];
list
```

Comment: *nice*, probably the most efficient way of converting strings to numbers.

Answer (score 6):

```
ToExpression[StringSplit["      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000"]]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
str = "      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000";

StringCases[str, x : NumberString :> ToExpression[x]]
```

> {1, 1, 3212, 8., 75, 61, 1, 74, 3, 58, 0.}

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58   0.0000";

Rest @ Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Number"]][str]
```

{1, 1, 3212, 8., 75, 61, 1, 74, 3, 58, 0.}

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you had the right idea:

```
r = ToExpression[
    "      1      1   3212    8.0000       75  61   1  74  3   58      0.0000",
    InputForm,
    Hold
]
r //FullForm

(*
Hold[3212 8. 75 61 74 3 58 0.]

Hold[Times[1,1,3212,8.`,75,61,1,74,3,58,0.`]]
*)
```

The formatted output (in [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm)) does not show "superfluous" unit multiplicands. However, they are still there when you look at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm)