# Find all runs in a string containing only numbers

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

The documentation has the following example to find all runs in a string containing only `"a"` and `"b"`:

```
StringCases["aababbcccdbaa", ("a" | "b") ..]
{"aababb", "baa"}
```

I would like to find all runs in a string containing only numbers. E.g.,

```
findnumbers["DataSummary_1N_5M_10L.dat"]
{"1", "5", "10"}
```

What is the nice way to do this, besides just writing out explicitly in the second argument of StringCases `("1" | "2" | "3" | "4" |`...etc... `) ..`? Thanks!

Comment: check `DigitCharacter` or `NumberString`.

Comment: at least closely related: [8938](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8938/5478)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also related: [(73172)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73172/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = "DataSummary_1N_5M_10L.dat";

StringCases[data, NumberString]
```

> {"1", "5", "10"}

Comment: `StringCases[str, DigitCharacter ..]` should also work.

Comment: Indeed, it does ! Very elegant